# Extending the derivative to a boundary point

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: [0, 1] → ℝ$ be a continuous function and continuously differentiable on the interior $(0, 1)$. Assume furthermore that $\lim_{x→0}f'(x) ≕ D$ exists. Then $f$ is right-differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0) = D$.

Is there some easier way to see this than mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean value theorem implies this:

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}= f^\prime(\xi)$$
for some $\xi\in (0,x)$. If now $x$ tends to $0$, $\xi$ will, too. By assumption, the rhs converges, hence by definition of differentiability the claim follows.

Edit: note that you don't need $f^\prime$ to be continuous for this reasoning.

Comment: Great. So simple and more general :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ be the continuous extension of $f'$ to $[0, 1)$, i.e. $g(0) = D$. Then for any $x ∈ (0, 1)$ we know that $g$ is continuous on $[0, x]$ and so the integral $$G(x, h) ≔ \int_h^xg(t)dt$$ is well-defined, finite and depends continuously on $h ∈ [0, 1)$. For $h > 0$ we know that $G(x, h) = f(x) - f(h)$ according to the fundamental theorem of analysis. Because both sides are continuous the equation holds at $h=0$: $$f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^xg(t)dt$$
Now again the fundamental theorem of analysis says that $f'(0) = g(0)$, which we wanted to show.